# Add drop shadow to SwiftUI Path elements

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, shadow

I have a rudimentary `ClockView` build with SwiftUI. :) My question is if applying drop shadows to the clock-hands is easily possible with this approach or if i need a different layout and grouping of the elements? I've tried to find a way to add shadows to `Path`, but got stuck. Thank you.

### Code

```
import SwiftUI

struct ClockView: View {
    @Binding var time : TimeValue
    let hoursHandWidth = 10
    let minutesHandWidth = 10
    let secondsHandWidth = 10

    var body: some View {

        return(
            ZStack {
                // clock-face
                Path { path in
                    let seconds : Path = Path(CGRect(x: 100, y: -0.5, width: 10, height: 1))
                    for i in 0...60 {
                        …
                        }
                }
                .fill(Color(red: 0.3, green: 0.3, blue: 0.3, opacity: 1.0))
                Path { path in
                    let hours : Path = Path(CGRect(x: 100, y: -1, width: 12, height: 2))
                    for i in 0...12 {
                        …
                        }
                }
                .fill(Color(red: 0.3, green: 0.3, blue: 0.3, opacity: 1.0))
                Path { path in
                    let threehours : Path = Path(CGRect(x: 95, y: -2, width: 20, height: 4))
                    for i in 0...4 {
                        …
                        }
                }
                .fill(Color.red)
                // clock-hands
                Path { path in
                    let minutehand : Path = Path(CGRect(x: 0, y: -(minutesHandWidth/2), width: 95, height: minutesHandWidth))
                    path.addPath(minutehand, …)
                }
                .fill(Color.blue)
                Path { path in
                    let hourhand : Path = Path(CGRect(x: 0, y: -(hoursHandWidth/2), width: 72, height: hoursHandWidth))
                    path.addPath(hourhand, …)
                }
                .fill(Color.blue)
                Path { path in
                    let secondshand : Path = Path(CGRect(x: 0, y: -(secondsHandWidth/2), width: 97, height: secondsHandWidth))
                    path.addPath(secondshand, …)
                }
                .fill(Color.yellow)
                .animation(.easeInOut)
                Path { path in
                    path.addPath(Path(CGPath(ellipseIn: CGRect(x: -5, y: -5, width: 10, height: 10), transform: nil)))
                }
                .fill(Color.black)
            }
            .offset(CGSize(width: 150, height: 150))
            .frame(width: 300, height: 300, alignment: .topLeading)
            .scaleEffect(1.2)
            .background(Color(red: 0.8, green: 0.8, blue: 0.8, opacity: 1.0))
        )
    }
 }
```

### Look

[image]

### ** Update **

I've applied `.shadow(..)` as user Asperi [recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61813553/5924595):

```
        Path { path in
            let secondshand : Path = Path(CGRect(x: 0, y: -(secondsHandWidth/2), width: 97, height: secondsHandWidth))
            path.addPath(secondshand, transform: .init(rotationAngle: 2.0 * CGFloat.pi * CGFloat(time.seconds-15)/60.0))
        }
        .fill(Color.yellow)
        .shadow(color: .black, radius: 8, x: 1, y: 1)
```

But the result is not exactly what i expected :)

[image]

Comment: Path { .. }.shadow(radius: 10) does not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've moved the transformation (rotation) from the subpath to the resulting path. Now it looks good.

**Old**:

```
   Path { path in
      let secondshand : Path = Path(CGRect(x: 0, y: -(secondsHandWidth/2), width: 97, height: secondsHandWidth))
      path.addPath(secondshand, transform: .init(rotationAngle: 2.0 * CGFloat.pi * CGFloat(time.seconds-15)/60.0))
   }
   .fill(Color.yellow)
   .shadow(color: .black, radius: 2)
```

**New**:

```
   Path { path in
      let secondshand : Path = Path(CGRect(x: 0, y: -(secondsHandWidth/2), width: 97, height: secondsHandWidth))
      path.addPath(secondshand)
   }
   .fill(Color.yellow)
   .shadow(color: .black, radius: 2)
   .transformEffect(CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: 2.0 * CGFloat.pi * CGFloat(time.seconds-15)/60.0))
```

### Look (new):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example

```
Path { path in
    let secondshand : Path = Path(CGRect(x: 0, y: -(secondsHandWidth/2), width: 97, height: secondsHandWidth))
    path.addPath(secondshand)
}
.fill(Color.yellow)
.shadow(color: .black, radius: 8, x: 4, y: 1)
```

Comment: thank you. There is a shadow now, but pls see the update in my OP.

Comment: @mark61, this is just a demo of shadow, you should calculate offsets instead of hardcoding, or use default, eg `.shadow(radius: 8)`